# Flutter ToggleButton Class - Flutter 1.9.1

Tags: flutter, dart

I am currently learning Flutter and making good progress so please bear with me if this is a noob question.

Flutter recently updated to 1.9.1 and with that came the new widget ToggleButton Class;

It was just what I was after so I have implemented the widget in my code as follow

```
var isSelected1 = [false, true];
var isSelected2 = [false, true];

ToggleButtons(
                borderColor: Colors.black,
                fillColor: Colors.grey,
                borderWidth: 2,
                selectedBorderColor: Colors.black,
                selectedColor: Colors.white,
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(0),
                children: [
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                    child: Text(
                      'Open 24 Hours',
                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                    child: Text(
                      'Custom Hours',
                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
                onPressed: (int index) {
                  setState(() {
                    for (int buttonIndex = 0;
                        buttonIndex < isSelected2.length;
                        buttonIndex++) {
                      if (buttonIndex == index) {
                        isSelected2[buttonIndex] = true;
                      } else {
                        isSelected2[buttonIndex] = false;
                      }
                    }
                  });
                },
                isSelected: isSelected2,
              ),`
```

What I am trying to do is display a widget when a button is selected.

I have tried numerous ways with the if, and, else statements and so far I cant figure it out.

for example

```
if (buttonIndex == index[0]) {
 // code here} 
else {
 //code here}
```

Where am I going wrong?

Thank you!

Answer (score 40, accepted):

```
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

    class SamplePage extends StatefulWidget {
    @override
    _SamplePageState createState() => _SamplePageState();
    }

    class _SamplePageState extends State<SamplePage> {
    List<bool> isSelected;

    @override
    void initState() {
        isSelected = [true, false];
        super.initState();
    }

    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
            title: Text('ToggleButtons'),
        ),
        body: Center(
            child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
            children: <Widget>[
                ToggleButtons(
                borderColor: Colors.black,
                fillColor: Colors.grey,
                borderWidth: 2,
                selectedBorderColor: Colors.black,
                selectedColor: Colors.white,
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(0),
                children: <Widget>[
                    Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                    child: Text(
                        'Open 24 Hours',
                        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16),
                    ),
                    ),
                    Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                    child: Text(
                        'Custom Hours',
                        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16),
                    ),
                    ),
                ],
                onPressed: (int index) {
                    setState(() {
                    for (int i = 0; i < isSelected.length; i++) {
                        isSelected[i] = i == index
                    }
                    });
                },
                isSelected: isSelected,
                ),
            ],
            ),
        ),
        );
    }
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much!! Absolute brilliant response!

Comment: thanks, don't forget to upvote and check as right answer.

Comment: Yes, that works. How would I do that if there was 3 toggle boxes to choose from? Thank you once again.

Comment: add one more child and add that boolean in array false.

Comment: omg, ` if (i == index) { isSelected[i] = true; } else {isSelected[i] = false; }` can be replaced with `isSelected[i] = i == index`

Comment: Hey, I just discovered this but if you ever want the toggle to start on the other side you have to set isSelected to [false, true] instead of [true, false]