# how to make day and time List horizontal view from api with two button to scrolling the list view with flutter

Tags: api, listview, flutter, horizontal-scrolling, setstate

I have in flutter day and time page view, when the user click time setState the clicked time to the grey color, and setState the others to the transparent color,
[in this image you can see the selected date](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jQ8dd.jpg)
please note that the user can re select again so the old selection setState
to the transparent color.

Comment: I think this dartpad answers your question https://dartpad.dev/132db523c9369a265d2614f8908693bb see column1 widget it selects one(red color) out of many boxes(green color) those boxes have to be your time items in list view,

Comment: no, it's not, this is for one column, I'm using many column in page view

Comment: The Image you posted by that I understand that you have many cards (A Horizontal ListView) each card has a column so you can use that for one column and rest is reusing the widget by using some kind of ListView or PageView

Comment: someone told me that I should use stream controler, but he didn't explain how that should help me.