# flutter blank page in page view

Tags: flutter, dart, scroll, pageviews, flutter-pageview

[image: my page view]

I have this page view in flutter and I get a blank page on the first page, how to solve this problem?

```
          PageView.builder(
              physics: new NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
              itemCount: allDays.length,
              controller: _pageController,
              itemBuilder: ( context, int index) {
                return index == 0 ? Container() : _listDay(index-1);
              },
            )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the itemBuilder, you are returning an empty Container for index 0. As the index is zero-based, index 0 is the first page. Try the following:

```
  PageView.builder(
      physics: new NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
      itemCount: allDays.length,
      controller: _pageController,
      itemBuilder: ( context, int index) {
        return _listDay(index);
      },
    )
```

Comment: that's worked dear, the widget was list view and i convert it to the page view,
can you help me with this too?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60277469/how-to-make-day-and-time-list-horizontal-view-from-api-with-two-button-to-scroll